# Couldn't run bat file through Java code

Tags: java

Problem is that the same code below is working on other machine with Windows 7. I also use Windows 7, and bat file works well. But if I try to run this bat from code written before, cmd window just blink once and disappear.

```
s =  path + "makeInfomap.bat";  

try {   
    p = run.exec(s); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);  
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}  

final int exitVal = p.waitFor();
```

Comment: what happens if you open a cmd window and run the bat at the command line, do you get an error?

Comment: It works fine.No errors.

Answer (score 2):

Run don't walk to this link: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

It will tell you how to gobble output and error streams and will tell you how to call the OS's command interpreter when doing similar programs (although it is a little out of date).

Comment: There is no any errors. The same programm working well on other machine. Every bat file(even simple like echo smth pause) wich I run from java doesn't work - dos windows blinking once and that's all. Thanks for link!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that java is calling it fine but that the batch file itself is running in to trouble.

Try adding a 'pause' as the last line of your batch file and see if the batch file's console gives you any usable information.

Comment: I tried it, it si not working. bat file by itself works fine. Thanks for trying.